# Что означает "челейка-шориянка"?

Tags: значение-слов, поэзия

В известном стихе Елены Александровны Благининой "Как мы готовили толкан-муку" есть строчки:

Напазакова Марьянка
Притащила таз муки.
Она – челейка-шориянка,
Бегает быстро, аж летит.

Вот я не понимаю, что значит "челейка-шориянка"?

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю. Тюркские народы ещё подразделяются по родам (сеок). Подробнее см.

https://www.analizfamilii.ru/Cheleykin/proishozhdenie.html

http://tadarlar.ru/seok-chelej.html

То есть шорская женщина из рода Челей.

Answer (score 0):

***Шориянка*** - представительница народа шорцев, жителей Горной Шории.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D1%8B
http://tadarlar.ru/shoriyanka.html

А вот ***челейка*** - тут могут быть варианты.
К сожалению, с творчеством этого автора не знаком, контекст представить не могу.
Скорее всего - жена или дочь какого-то искусного мастера, "челейками" (или "челеями"?) вроде бы шорцы звали своих ремесленников. Могло ли это слово обозначать женщину-ремесленника (искусную повариху как можно трактовать контекст стиха) - вот не знаю. Я немного знаком с культурой малых тюркоязычных народов Сибири, как-то не по менталитету тамошнему женщину считать ремесленником. С другой стороны автор мог немного посвоевольницать и наградить женщину мужским эпитетом.

Короче, либо жена/дочь мастера, либо местный аналог нашей "Марьи-искусницы".